# Ruby gem install says "you don't have write permissions" on Mac

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, rubymine

please, i need help!!! i am really new on all this installation i try to install ruby mine and it s give me all time this error 'Cucumber gem ist't installed for ruby -2.0.0 - p 481 SDC' i have mac and install one universal version of ruby when i put it on terminal - it s always give me this answer

```
tests-MBP:~ annasena$ gem install cucumber 
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) 
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Comment: Please format the question properly.

Comment: How did you install ruby?

Comment: i install ruby from this link https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/

Comment: guys don't downvote total noobs.  You were one once.  You need a proper install of a modern ruby.  I recommend https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: i am all ready use command sudo gem install cucumber, and it s give this error tests-MBP:~ annasena$ sudo gem install cucumber
Password:
ERROR:  Error installing cucumber:
 cucumber-core requires Ruby version >= 2.1.
tests-MBP:~ annasena$    and i can t install 2.1 , because for mac exist only universal 2.0

Comment: How about you install ruby with [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/) and dont use system ruby? Here is [an article about that](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby)

Comment: OMG,i DO it. install version of ruby 2.1.0 for this link rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory. (mac user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126403/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-3-0-directory-ma)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the system-wide Ruby, and it stores its gems in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0`.

In order to install gems into a system location, you need root permissions.
To give `gem install` root access, you just run it with `sudo`:

```
sudo gem install cucumber
```

Comment: i am all ready use command sudo gem install cucumber, and it s give this error tests-MBP:~ annasena$ sudo gem install cucumber Password: ERROR: Error installing cucumber: cucumber-core requires Ruby version >= 2.1. tests-MBP:~ annasena$ and i can t install 2.1 , because for mac exist only universal 2.0

Comment: @AnnaSena Use RVM instead to install Ruby locally under your own user account. Go to rvm.io and follow the instructions there. That way you can install any Ruby version you like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem people run into with Ruby on a Mac. As some people have mentioned in the comments here, the best way to install Ruby on a Mac is with a version manager. Even though Macs come with Ruby already installed, that version of Ruby should not be used for installing gems. And whatever you do, you should [never use sudo to install gems](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-should-never-use-sudo-to-install-ruby-gems/).

For more details on how to install Ruby with a version manager, check out my  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873916/928191) to a similar question here on Stack Overflow.