# You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory. (mac user)

Tags: macos, rubygems, installation, bundler, atom-editor

below is what I need to do.

> To run the specs, you'll need to install RSpec. First, run `gem install bundler` in the root directory of your project. Then, run `bundle install`. To run a single spec file, run a command like this: `bundle exec rspec spec/00_hello_spec.rb`. To run all of the specs at once, run `bundle exec rspec`.

So, I typed `gem install bundler` in Terminal, and got the error:

> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.

and this was in the project file in atom

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "rspec", "~> 3.2.0"
```

My question is:

It seems like terminal is giving me the response because I'm not supposed to change anything on ruby, and I need to `bundle install` inside of atom? Could anyone tell me how to use atom or run anything in atom?

Comment: Simply use following command `sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Ruby/Gems/`

Comment: Set global ruby version like this `rbenv global 3.1.2` then it will work.

Comment: @FaizFareed I tried this and am still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @jarrodwhitley you should update your system OS accordingly

Comment: None of these worked for me but https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1267#issuecomment-730126503 did

Answer (score 574):

You are correct that macOS won't let you change anything with the Ruby version that comes installed with your Mac. However, it's possible to install gems like `bundler` using a separate version of Ruby that doesn't interfere with the one provided by Apple.

Using `sudo` to install gems, or changing permissions of system files and directories is strongly discouraged, even if you know what you are doing. Can we please stop providing this bad advice?

The solution involves two main steps:

1. Install a separate version of Ruby that does not interfere with the one that came with your Mac.
2. Update your `PATH` such that the location of the new Ruby version is first in the `PATH`. Some tools do this automatically for you. If you're not familiar with the `PATH` and how it works, it's one of the basics that you should learn, and you'll understand why you sometimes get "command not found" errors and how to fix them.

First, you will want to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), which installs the prerequisite command line tools, and makes it easy to install other necessary tools.

Then, the two easiest ways to install a separate version of Ruby are:

#### If you would like the flexibility of easily switching between many Ruby versions [RECOMMENDED]

Choose one of these four options:

- [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) and [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install). These can be installed with Homebrew:

```bash
brew install chruby ruby-install
```

- [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) - can be installed with Homebrew
- [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)
- [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/#/)

If you chose `chruby` and `ruby-install`, you can then install the latest Ruby like this:

```
ruby-install ruby
```

Once you've installed everything and configured your `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile` according to the instructions from the tools above, quit and restart Terminal, then switch to the version of Ruby that you want. In the case of `chruby`, it would be something like this:

```bash
chruby 3.1.3
```

Whether you need to configure `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile` depends on which shell you're using.

#### If you know for sure you don't need more than one version of Ruby at the same time (besides the one that came with macOS) [NOT RECOMMENDED]

Even if you think you won't need another version now, you will eventually and you won't be able to easily switch. This will cause confusion and headaches, which is why I don't recommend installing and managing Ruby with Homebrew.

**If you choose to use Homebrew to install Ruby despite my warnings, you'll be on your own if you run into any issues.**

- Install ruby with Homebrew:

```
brew install ruby
```

Then update your `PATH` by running this command:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

The `3.1.0` in the command above assumes Homebrew installed a Ruby version that starts with `3.1`. If it installed a different version, replace `3.1` with the first two digits of your Ruby version.

If you're on an M1/M2 Mac, replace `/usr/local` with `/opt/homebrew`

Then "refresh" your shell for these changes to take effect:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Or you can open a new terminal tab, or quit and restart Terminal.

Replace `.zshrc` with `.bash_profile` if you are using Bash. If you're not sure, read my guide to find out which shell you're using.

To check that you're now using the non-system version of Ruby, you can run the following commands:

```
which ruby
```

It should **not** be `/usr/bin/ruby`

```
ruby -v
```

It should be 3.1.3 or later.

Once you have this new version of Ruby installed, you can now install bundler (or any other gem):

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: if you're like me and you use zsh (or another shell other than bash), there is an extra step!  After installing `rbenv` you have to do `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile`.  [Source](https://gist.github.com/stonehippo/cc0f3098516fb52390f1)

Comment: If you face a permission error on /usr/local directory, run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282002/error-of-error-could-not-lock-config-file-git-config-permission-denied-occu) for more info

Comment: Since MacOS is encouraging people to switch to zsh, you should also apply the change to ~/.bash_profile to ~/.zshrc.

Comment: I installed ruby with rbenv, and `which ruby` does return `/usr/bin/ruby`. Should I find where the new (rbenv installation) of ruby is located and update the PATH so that location appears before the Mac installation?

Comment: Except of course... "you don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

Comment: @monfresh I followed your steps.. following is the output:
$ which ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby

$ ruby -v
ruby 3.1.1p18 (2022-02-18 revision 53f5fc4236) [x86_64-darwin21]

HOWEVER, when I try to install cocoapods using:
$ gem install cocoapods
I get:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/omkarbojjawar/.local/share/gem/specs

Please help.

Comment: If you are on Monterey on a M1 Mac the echo command should look like this:


`echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
`

Comment: For me ruby-v gives the version of the macOS ruby. Is there a way i can check which version of ruby is installed by homebrew?

Comment: Please search for @Mick answer regarding `rebenv`. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Had to `brew install xz` before `ruby-install ruby` before it failed with `xzcat: command not found`

Comment: For me on M1 ruby-install gave architecture error `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 _rb_arithmetic_sequence_extract referenced from...`

Found the article https://www.rubyonmac.dev/how-to-install-ruby-on-macos-12-6-apple-silicon which suggested to use a flag like this: `ruby-install 3.1.2 -- --enable-shared`

And it worked

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I wrote that article, but I forgot to update this answer. However, now that Ruby 3.1.3 is released, that workaround is no longer needed.

Answer (score 306):

Worked for me using the parameter `--user-install` running following command:

```
gem install name_of_gem --user-install
```

> Install in user's home directory instead of `GEM_HOME`

https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-install

> RubyGems’ default local repository can be overridden with the GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME environment variables. GEM_HOME sets the default repository to install into. GEM_PATH allows multiple local repositories to be searched for gems.

**Edit**

There was one gem I still could not install (it required the Ruby.h headers of the Ruby development kit or something), then I tried the different version managers, but somehow that still did not really work as it was stated in the documentations how to just install and switch (it did just not switch the versions).
Then I removed all the installed version managers and installed afterwards with `brew install ruby` the latest version and did set the PATH variable, too. (It will be mentioned after the installation of ruby from brew), which worked.

Comment: This worked well for me; I just needed to also add the bin path (`~/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin` in my case) to my $PATH. Didn't need to install an extra Ruby or pay for the current top answer's installation script.

Answer (score 168):

If you don't want to run `sudo` then install ruby using homebrew

```
brew install ruby
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
gem install rails
```

You may want to add `export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"` to your `~/.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` if you're using zsh

**Note:** RubyGems keeps old versions of gems, so feel free to do some cleaning after updating:

```
gem cleanup
```

Comment: didnt help on Catalina OS 

Comment: `Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command`

Comment: It sounds like you are trying run a `rails` command. The last two commands I have do not run `rails` command. Try to open a new terminal outside of your project then copy last two lines of my answer one by one.

Comment: don't forget to `source ~/. zshrc` (or `~/.bash_profile`)

Comment: Working for me on Catilina 10.15.4, I did remove rvm rbenv and then installed rbenv. Then updated my .zshrc , sourced it(aka $ ```source ~/.zshrc```) and then rails installed flawlessly. Thanks for the PATH correction.

Comment: This worked for me - I use Catalina as well. I didn't want the messiness of using sudo, so thanks!

Comment: It works on macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me. After I use this command
`export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"`

Answer (score 127):

Just export GEM_HOME:

```
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
```

And then try:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: As someone who used RVM to install Ruby and Rails on OSX, this worked well for me and is much simpler than the other posted solutions.

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/kanchan/.local/share/gem/specs

Comment: give permission to the specified directory.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue @WannaBeGeek?
@MuhammadNaeemParacha can you guide me on how to allow that permission?

Comment: sudo chown -R /Users/kanchan/.local/share/gem/*

Comment: @MuhammadNaeemParacha it didn't work.. here's my code:
 sudo chown -R /Users/myName/.local/share/gem/*
Password:
usage: chown [-fhnvx] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
       chown [-fhnvx] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
Please help.

Comment: what's the error now ?

Comment: @MuhammadNaeemParacha after doing $ sudo gem install cocoapods it says Successfully installed cocoapods-1.11.3. However while I run or use Flutter doctor, I get [!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3)
    • Xcode at /Volumes/ssd/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.

Comment: After installing the latest ruby version with rbenv, this was the easiest way to fix the permission issue when installing global gems.

Comment: You're an absolute lifesaver. So much easier than the other posted solutions

Comment: Please correct your answer with description of what would happen after making this code.

Comment: Literally spent 2-3 hours before finding this solution :) Thanks @MuhammadNaeemParacha

Answer (score 92):

As @idleberg mentions, on Mac OS, it is best to install [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to avoid permissions errors when using manually installed ruby.

### Installation

```
$ brew update
$ brew install rbenv
```

Add the following in `.bashrc` file:

```sh
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Now, we can look at the list of ruby versions available for install

```sh
$ rbenv install -l
```

Install version 2.3.8 for example

```sh
$ rbenv install 2.3.8
```

Now we can use this ruby version globally

```sh
$ rbenv global 2.3.8
```

Finally run

```sh
$ rbenv rehash
```

```sh
$ which ruby
/Users/myuser/.rbenv/shims/ruby
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

### Go for it

Now install bundler

```sh
$ gem install bundler
```

All done!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

Worked for me

Comment: This is the only method that's worked for me. Tried installing rbenv and used multiple Ruby versions without any progress.

Comment: Warning: This can cause problems in the future.

Comment: works for me dear.

Comment: Perfect! Got mine working with this.

Answer (score 15):

It's generally recommended to use a version manager like [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [`rvm`](https://github.com/rvm/rvm). Otherwise, installed Gems will be available as `root` for other users.

If you know what you're doing, you can use `sudo gem install`.

Answer (score 14):

> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.

In my case, the issue was related to ruby access some how the ruby path was messed up in my system.

The below steps helped me resolve the problem

1. Open the terminal
2. Install ruby using homebrew

> [for fresh install] `brew install ruby`

> [for reinstalling] `brew reinstall ruby`

3. Check the path of ruby using the below command

   `which ruby`
4. It should be installed in the below path

   `/usr/bin/ruby`
5. To change the ruby path to the user path

To check which shell is used by your system

```
echo $0

-zsh
```

> For zshrc

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >>~/.zshrc`

> For bash

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >>~/~/.bashrc`

6. Quit and relaunch the terminal
7. After changing the path with step 5
8. Check for the path of the ruby again (execute step 3 - please make sure the path displays as given below)

`/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`

> [if you don't quit and launch the terminal, step 4 path will be shown]

9. This step may not be applicable to everyone can skip step 10 & 11, if you have the correct Cocoapods version installed

Check the version of the pod installed

`pod --version`

10. Uninstall the specific version of Cocoapods using the below command

> In case the version installed is 1.11.0

`gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.11.0`

11. Install the Cocoapods of the specific version

    gem install cocoapods -v 1.11.0
12. Change the path to the Project directory cd {path of the project directory}
13. Install the bundler in the project directory

`bundle install`

14. Execute pod install

`pod install`

Comment: In M1 chip - I got the issue. After step 5 path was not changed a nd again it is showing the step 4 always. What can I do? I have reopened he terminal after quit. but no use. Any specific cmd we use to change the path.

Comment: My ruby installed version is `ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]`

Comment: You are herooo!

Answer (score 10):

Run this

```
$ rbenv init
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.zshrc:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Follow instructions, (in my case add to *~/.zshrc*)  ;)

---

Also important: Changes only take effect if you reboot your console. Two options

- Enter `source <modified file>`
- close and open again

Comment: I upgraded to Catalina (which switches from bash to zsh) and I forgot to copy everything from `.bash_profile` over to `.zshrc`

Comment: This works! Don't use `sudo`! 

In case you don't use ZSH, you can add this to your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`. A great way to check if this works is to use `which ruby`, it should point to a path which has `rbenv` and not to `/usr/local/ruby`.

Answer (score 9):

PLEASE USE SUDO WITH CARE!!!!!! ONLY IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING!!!!!!!!!!!!

I have faced same issue after install macOS Catalina. I had try below command and its working.

```
sudo gem update
```

Comment: By far the simplest solution for anyone who doesn't want to do a full-blown installation of ruby + package managers + etc etc.

Comment: You should never ever use `sudo` to install any kind of development dependencies you don't have control over.

Answer (score 8):

Tested on M1 MacBook Air (assuming Homebrew installed)

Following to the top answer, we can run:

```
brew install chruby ruby-install
```

To install the latest stable ruby:

```
ruby-install ruby
```

Then get the version number by running:

```
chruby
```

In your ~/.zshrc file:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
chruby 3.1.2
```

The "3.1.2" is the output I got when running chruby. Make sure you add that one line at the end.

Remember to restart the terminal each time you install a new gem.

Answer (score 7):

To fix this, I ran

```sh
brew reinstall ruby
```

which showed me this message

> ```
> ==> Caveats
> ==> ruby
> By default, binaries installed by gem will be placed into:
>   /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin
>
> You may want to add this to your PATH.
>
> ruby is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
> because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
> parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
>
> If you need to have ruby first in your PATH, run:
>   echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
> ```

So I added these two lines to my `~/.bashrc` file

```sh
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin:$PATH"
```

Then I opened a new Terminal.app window and ran my `gem install` command again and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Try 1 or 2

```
1 - $ gem install cocoapods
2 - $ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

if it doesn't work, then export GEM_HOME:

```
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
```

And try again:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

Remember the oficial doc says you can use sudo (https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started).

Comment: `export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"` worked for me

Comment: WOW... This worked for me `export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"`

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed ruby separately and installed ruby using rbenv/rvm you budler might point to different versions.

try

```
gem env home
```

and

```
ruby -v
```

both should point to same version.check you have installed ruby using rbenv/rvm, If so delete the ruby version you installed separately.

In order for gem to work, you must invoke rbenv,

```
rbenv shell <ruby version>
```

and

```
rbenv global <ruby version>
```

I am not sure how RVM works.
Let me know if this works.

Comment: was missing setting the shell and global. Why isn't that in rbenv instructions 

Comment: Not sure, why this was missed, I was able to find out after trying out.

Answer (score 4):

I deleted those directories by using the below command

```
sudo rm -rf \
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/{build_info,cache,doc,extensions,gems} \
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications/*.gemspec \
  /Library/Ruby/Site
```

then installed cocoa pods using `sudo gem install cocoapods`
and it worked for me. Thanks

Comment: This solved my problem when install gollum and cocoapods

Answer (score 4):

After install `rbenv` ,I also have this problem , add this line in my `.bashrc` :

`eval "$(rbenv init -)"`

solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I also struggled with this Ruby problem and finally found an easy and working solution for Mac with M1 chip.

To install Ruby I used a simple ruby manager called **chruby** (https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#readme)

**Steps:**

1. Install Homebrew (video guide here: https://youtu.be/IWJKRmFLn-g)
2. Install chruby with command:

```
brew install chruby ruby-install
```

3. Install the latest ruby version with command:

```
ruby-install ruby
```

4. Edit .zshrc file. You can use nano or any other text editor.
   .zshrc file is located in root directory and is a hidden file.
   This file is responsible for Terminal commands.

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

5. Add these two lines to .zshrc file and save it. Instead of *3.2.2* put Ruby version you installed in Step 3. It will make Terminal use selected version of Ruby.

```
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
chruby 3.2.2
```

6. Close and reopen Terminal
7. Check which version of Ruby is currently in use with command:

```
ruby -v
```

Answer (score 3):

For latest OS versions

1. First run sudo xcode-select --switch /
2. sudo gem install cocoapods --user-install

this did it for me

Comment: Thank you, you solution works with me, I was looking for this answer to fix cocoapods on my mac!

Answer (score 3):

for Mac OS 12 and above also for 13
Xcode 14 and above

first you call

export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
after that
gem install cocoapods

home its help you ☺️

Comment: Lifesaver... quick and effective.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

In several occasions, I've solved this kind of errors by just closing my terminal session and opening a new one before retrying the failing command.

**Long explanation**

In some SOs (such as MacOS) there is already a pre-installed, system-wide version of ruby. If you are using a version manager, such as `rbenv` or `asdf`, they work by playing with the environment of your current session so that the relevant commands point to the binaries installed by the version manager.

When installing a new binary, the version manager installs it in a special location, usually somewhere under the user's home directory. It then configures everything in your `PATH` so that you get the freshly installed binaries when you issue a command, instead of the ones that came with your system. However, if you don't restart the session (there are other ways of getting your environment updated, but that's the easiest one) you don't get the new configuration and you will be using the original installation.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error because I forgot to run the following after installing ruby:

`source ~/.zshrc` - or other ~/...rc file depending on your terminal

Answer (score 2):

rbenv global 2.6.3 helped me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A different installation of ruby should be used. I use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) for that purpose.

```
# install your version of ruby
$ rbenv install 2.0.0-p247

# modify .ruby_version on current directory
$ rbenv local 2.0.0-p247

# proceed installing gems
$ gem install bundler
```

Disclamer: I am not a ruby person. This worked for me and if you are a ruby expert and see things to change in this answer, please, go ahead or comment!

Answer (score 1):

I was using the below command to install fastlane but didn't worked

> gem install fastlane -NV

So using `sudo` to install gems worked for me and it would be like

> sudo gem install fastlane -NV

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) by passing this into your terminal

   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
2. Install cocoapods using brew

   brew install cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

I try it, and work to me
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:$PATH
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/include"
gem install ffi

Answer (score 1):

First, run the following command to install Ruby Gems in your user directory:

> gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.3 --user-install

Answer (score 1):

What solved the issue for me:
add to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Then Ruby version of local directory is picked correctly instead of system Ruby version being picked. And I was able to install bundler

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for Mac

1. Install/update [RVM](https://rvm.io) with last ruby version

   `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
2. Install [bundler](https://bundler.io)

   `gem install bundler`

---

after this two commands `(sudo) gem install ....` started to work

Comment: may need to also specify `rvm use <version>`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for MAC. run the command

```
sudo gem update
```

then type your Mac password when prompted

Answer (score 0):

After trying the previous approaches, this worked for me on Big Sur:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: This worked for me using macOS 11.6. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After install ruby with rbenv you also need to set global ruby. For that you can do like, `rbenv global 3.2.1` then install bundler with `gem install bundler`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

**I messed up with this problem for a few days, finally its working well, thanks to the inspiration from:**

1. [BlackRainbow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1508806/blackrainbow) - Setup Jenkins $PATH variable
2. [Moncef Belyamani](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-should-never-use-sudo-to-install-ruby-gems/) - Why You Should Never Use sudo to Install Ruby

**What Exactly I Do**:

> 1. Used [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#readme) to manage my Ruby environment
> 2. Open terminal and execute `echo $PATH`
> 3. Copy the result and paste to Jenkinsfile
> 4. Re-try to build your pipeline
> 5. Thats it, and its working well in my enviroment

**Attachment:**

> *Step 1-2 To Configure Ruby & Get Path Env* [image: -]

---

> *Step 2-3 To Configure Jenkinsfile* [image: -]

---

> *Step 4 Build Pipeline* [image: -]

Answer (score 0):

I created a **Kotlin Multiplatform App** for the first time and got **CocoaPods not installed error** during the Build time by Android Studio. Then, I wanted to install CocoaPods for using the KMM project;

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

When I tried to install it by the Terminal, I got this error:

```
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory directory
```

**Solution**
First, you should run this command in the Terminal:

```
brew install ruby-install chruby
```

Second, to enable auto-switching of Rubies specified by ruby-version files, add the following to **~/.bash_profile** or **~/.zshrc**:

```
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
```

Third, check the [Ruby stable versions](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and then add the following to **~/.bash_profile** or **~/.zshrc**:

```
chruby  ruby-3.3.0
```

Fourth, install the Ruby:

```
ruby-install --latest ruby
```

Now, you have to restart your terminal and then install [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) :

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Mojave with `rbenv`, this solution works for me:

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this line into the file:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to install rbenv and maintain ruby versions under rbenv.

1. `brew install rbenv`
2. `rbenv init`
3. append `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to ~/.bash_profile
4. `rbenv install {stable_version_#}` you can get version number using `rbenv install -L`
5. `rbenv global {your_preferred_version_#}` command use to switch to ruby versions
6. `rbenv shell {your_preferred_version_#}`
7. `gem install {whatever you want gems}`

More detail https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me on Mac

> sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

Answer (score -2):

Simply doing
`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` worked for me.