# You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory

Tags: macos, rubygems, bundle

When I use command `gem install bundler` in MacOS 10.13.x, the error is:

> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.

```
$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.16.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory. (mac user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126403/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-3-0-directory-ma)

Answer (score 41):

This is basically a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126403/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-3-0-directory-ma/54873916#54873916) question, where I already posted a detailed answer that solves the problem. Instead of maintaining two separate answers, I thought it would be better to just link to my answer here since the same solution applies:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873916/928191

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. For me, using zsh, the ruby install recommended the command `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`. After that, I ran `source ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: I wish I could accept this answer on the asker's behalf. A whole day spent trying to diagnose "mkmf.rb can’t find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h", "Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Library/Ruby/Gems", take ownership of the /System/Library folder, reset ruby to a blank state, restore with time machine, and finally wipe ruby from my Mac altogether, and I finally come across a solution

Answer (score 23):

As previously noted, on a Mac the system ruby is owned by root and it's not safe to install things against that version with sudo. If you do every gem runs as root and that's a security nightmare. **DO NOT DO THAT**

I'll walk you through my steps since previous answers assume a bit of command line foo and the added details might be of some use to someone.

Double-check we're running the old, system provided ruby

```
which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

(that's the system path)

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7
```

(the old version)

```
brew install ruby
```

or [install brew first](https://brew.sh)

at the end of which, the install says:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3
```

Make that show up in the path *first*

```
PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/bin:$PATH
```

Double-check

```
which ruby
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/bin/ruby
```

Double-check version

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.6.3p62
```

Make the path update permanent (otherwise you'll have to update the path each time you want to use ruby)

```
echo  PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin bundler
```

Comment: This is a bad practice and not recommended. Read more [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873916/928191)

Answer (score 1):

Best not to `sudo` all the way.

Proper way is to `source ~/.zshrc` works for me after you install the latest `ruby` in your Mac via `brew install ruby`