# Remove version of Ruby/RubyGems and gems on MacOS properly

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I recently installed a version of Ruby (and RubyGems) via homebrew on my Mac because the RubyGems that comes installed on Mac doesn't let you install gems due to permissions issues. I followed the instructions in the top answer in this thread: [You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory. (mac user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126403/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-3-0-directory-ma)

After installing some gems, I realized that I don't need this version of Ruby and RubyGems anymore, so I ran `brew uninstall ruby` to get rid of them (I assume RubyGems gets deleted along with Ruby). However, I checked and it appears the gems I had installed are still in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0`. Can I just delete the `usr/local/lib/ruby` folder, and is this the correct way of going about it? I don't know if the default RubyGems that comes with MacOS uses this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you run `rbenv versions` it will display all your ruby versions including the one installed by default (system).

- system ruby usually located in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.1`
- rbenv ruby default location is inside user path `~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/gems`

to uninstall ruby using rbenv you need to remove the specific version e.g `rbenv uninstall 2.5.1`

I suggest that you leave your ruby system installation, but you can remove all the gems inside the ruby system path manually `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of that top post in the link you mentioned. You are correct that Homebrew installs gems in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0`. You can confirm that in two ways:

- You can run `brew info ruby`, and then visit the Formula page that's displayed: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/ruby.rb
  This is the line of code where the Rubygems directory is defined: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/ruby.rb#L48
- You can install Ruby again with Homebrew, and you should see this section in the terminal output:

```
By default, binaries installed by gem will be placed into:
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin

You may want to add this to your PATH.
```

I wrote about this in the Homebrew section of my [definitive guide to installing Ruby gems on a Mac](http://localhost:4567/the-definitive-guide-to-installing-ruby-gems-on-a-mac/).

The system Ruby is NOT installed in `/usr/local/lib/ruby`. It is in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0`. You can safely remove the `/usr/local/lib/ruby` directory. On a fresh macOS installation, the `/usr/local` directory is empty.

You can then check if Homebrew is still healthy by running `brew doctor`.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0` used to be brew default install path. Now they have changed it to `/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0`. So you can delete  the previous folder under /usr without a problem.