# Running 'pod install' in Xcode project folder does not create .xcworkspace file

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Updated with error message below original post.

**Original post:**
I have a Swift project with following Podfile. Running 'pod install' in project folder does not create a .xcworkspace file and does not install any of the Pods.

I followed all instructions in 'Get Started' section of https://cocoapods.org, but still nothing.

What am I doing wrong? Running Xcode 12.1 on latest release of macOS Big Sur Public Beta.

```
target 'FY' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
end
```

**Update with error message:**
Clearly, Cocoapods are not getting installed due to issues /usr/bin. I used `sudo gem install cocoapods --verbose` to get the following error message. Also installed Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.1 and 12.2 from Developer Portal.

```
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/ext/ffi_c
["/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby", "-I", "/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0", "-r", "./siteconf20201025-16127-3uc1s5.rb", "extconf.rb"]
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:10:in `system_libffi_usable?'
    from extconf.rb:42:in `<main>'
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20201025-16127-3uc1s5.rb extconf.rb
Building has failed. See above output for more information on the failure.
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.13.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.13.1/gem_make.out
```

Error from mkmf.log

```
package configuration for libffi is not found
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin20 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS -DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib -L. -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib     -lruby.2.6   "
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: note: did not find header 'config.h' in framework 'ruby' (loaded from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Comment: Is there any error printed?

Comment: Please provide your console output

Comment: Hi everyone, Thanks for your help. I updated the original comment with error message. Help please!

Comment: Can you also check what's inside of the `mkmf.log` file at `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.13.1/mkmf.log`

Comment: Added mkmf.log error.

Comment: How did you install the command line tools? Through terminal? I'd try reinstalling those through the terminal.

Comment: Started installing command line tools through Developer Portal that asked to use software update. The updates then showed up in System Preferences -> Software Update.

Comment: I'd recommend to update ruby, update or reinstall gem. Remove the command line tools and reinstall them over the command line. And then try again. Make sure to always check the output of your commands. An installation might have finished but could still have caused an error. Don't skip on those errors.

Comment: Do `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` as shown in the answer and report back errors with *that* statement. Also, check your podfile as some of those are not needed or are different. Also, is this a macOS Project? If so in XCode, turn sandboxing OFF (as a test) and try it.

Answer (score 1):

### **Initialize cocoapods**

The first time you need to run `pod init` in your projects directory to initialise your project.

It will create the new xcworkspace AND pod file. Once this is done add your pods to the pod file and run `pod install`

Make sure the deployment target of your xcode project and the platform in the pod file are the same. For example ios 14.1.

### **Install pods**

If you want to add more pods, add them to your pod file and run `pod install` in your project directory again.

### **Update pods**

If you want to update all your pods run `pod update` in your project directory.

### **Removing individual pods from project**

Just delete the line from the pod file or comment it out and run `pod install` in your project directory again.

### **Removing cocoapods from project**

In some cases it might be necessary to completely remove cocoapods from your project. Run the following in your project directory.

`pod deintegrate`

`pod cache clean --all`

`rm Podfile`

If you are trying to reinstall it only, try `pod deintegrate` only, leaving the pod file and cache intact. Followed by `pod install`. If this doesn't work use all three commands above and start from the beginning.

You might have to install `pod deintegrate` and `pod clean` if you haven't done so yet. Run `sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean` to do that.

Credit to this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765245/12764795)

### **Installation notes**

Make sure cocoapods is installed correctly on your system. You can use `pod --version` and it should give you the installed version. If it says file not found, or similar, something is wrong.

Quite often `sudo gem install cocoapods` has issues with the `usr/bin` directory permissions. It should tell you that when trying to install.

Try `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` instead.

If this doesn't work try `sudo gem install cocoapods --verbose` and have a look at the output. Usually at the very end you will see the errors that caused the installation to fail.

Use the same command you used to install cocoapods to update to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you. I get the following error for pod init. ```zsh: command not found: pod```. I installed CocoaPods using ```sudo gem install cocoapods```. May I need to add a path to bash profile?

Comment: I've added to my answer. Make sure to check the installation note part.

Comment: And post any errors you are getting here in the comment or your original answer and I will update my answer accordingly. The more information you can give the better and watch closely not to overlook an error. : )

Comment: Hello Marco, Thanks for your detailed response. I updated the post with error message from console.

Answer (score 0):

The 'automated script' in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126403/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-3-0-directory-ma/53949737) helped fix the issue. Thanks everyone for your inputs and help. Thanks to the creator of the post and the automated script.