# Could not find 'ruby-macho' (~> 1.1) among 54 total gem(s)

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

Good afternoon, today I'm having problems on Mac OSX using `CocoaPods`. When I try to use:

```
'pod init'
'pod install'
```

I have the following error:

> Could not find 'ruby-macho' (~> 1.1) among 54 total gem(s)
> Gem:: MissingSpecError

I tried everything but terminal have a lot of problems and I don't know how to fix it

Thank you so much for your attention

Comment: have you tried `gem install ruby-macho`?

Comment: I have this error:

    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

Comment: You can get around that using these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126403/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-3-0-directory-ma

Comment: When I "install" ruby-macho says:

Done installing documentation for ruby-macho after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

Then, an error appeared:

 Could not find 'ruby-macho' (~> 1.1) - did find: [ruby-macho-2.5.0] (Gem::MissingSpecVersionError)

is weird :/