# cocoapods intallation Errors in mac for flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, rubygems, cocoapods, homebrew, flutter-doctor

I install Homebrew.
Then I run command
"brew install cocoapods". It install successfully
but in flutter doctor i got error: cocoapods installed but not working properly. Error because of ruby incompatible version.

Tried another method
"sudo gem install cocoapods"
and got error:

While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.

This is m1 pro 2020 machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory. (mac user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126403/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-3-0-directory-ma)

Answer (score 1):

For MAC M1 chip Users try this solution
install ffi first (if not) In regular terminal using command: sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi then arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
Run flutter clean
Once complete, rebuild your Flutter application: flutter run

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid linking with system ruby and download a new ruby version using brew:

```
brew install ruby
```

Then add this line to *.bash_profile* or *.zshrc*

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
```

Close the terminal and open it again, then run this line to make sure the default ruby is the newly installed:

```
which ruby
```

Uninstall gem cocoapods and download it using brew

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

- I recently came across the same issue and was able to solve it. Please try the post I created and see if it helps!
  NOTE: If you are using it for iOS App development you might want to change the version from `1.8.4` to `1.11.0`

For many silicon mac users this command might not work. I tried downgrading to this version and it  works just fine for me.

WORKS :

```bash
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

**Latest CocoaPods 1.10.0 won't work.**

Issues with : **MacOS 11.0, Ruby 2.6.0.**

Errors:

- `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapod`

  ```bash
  ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapod' (>= 0) in any repository
  ^[[A^CERROR:  Interrupted
  ```
- `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.3`

  ```bash
  Fetching zeitwerk-2.6.8.gem
  Fetching activesupport-6.1.7.3.gem
  ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
  You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
  ```