# -bash: rbenv: command not found

Tags: ruby, bash, jekyll, rbenv

Im trying to install jekyll through ruby rbnev and After putting open `~/.bash_profile` into the terminal and inputting `eval "$(rbenv init -bash)"` into the text editor, which was the only thing inside it, I closed everything and opened up terminal to see the above error message `-bash: rbenv: command not found`. No rbenv commands work and `gem install jekyll` yeilds the following:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

I looked all across the internet and couldn't find any help. Any help would be appreciated!

I tried almost everything. I've been stuck on this for 20 min. I detailed my path on the "details of the problem"

Comment: It is not clear to me, if and how you installed `rbenv` on your computer before you tried to configure it. Would you mind sharing? And what is your OS and shell?

Comment: Yeah of course, I'm not familiar with rbenv at all so i was watching a few videos for help. I downloaded rbenv on my computer using homebrew from the instructions on this recommended section on this link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126403/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-3-0-directory-ma
The problem of rbenv command not being found started when I added eval "$(rbenv init -bash)" into the .bash_profile.

Comment: If rbenv is not found, then it was not properly installed. You can always revert the changes you made to `.bash_profile` to make sure those changes you made are not what is causing the issue. At any time you can always run `rbenv init` yourself from the command line to make sure it works at all.

Comment: How about specifying the absolute path to `rbenv`?

Comment: You mention Homebrew; are you sure you are using `bash`, and not `zsh` (which has been the default user shell for a while now on macOS)? If `zsh`, then the correct file is `.zprofile`, not `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 3):

You made a typo.
The line in `.bash_profile` should be:

```
eval "$(rbenv init - bash)"
                    ^-- NOTE THE SPACE HERE
```